# How to animate a div only with CSS?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, animation

After a couple of hours looking for different kind of solutions, I didn't find the perfect answer for my answer knowing that I do not want to use JQuery.

I am trying to animate my div to make them appear with a slide up effect. I tried lots of different possibilities and even the easiest one :

```
 transition: all linear 2s;
```

Here is a snippet of my code :

http://plnkr.co/edit/illdCZoNorc9y7NFMt2F?p=preview

Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 5):

Your code actually works exactly like you are hoping *if* you add **['ngAnimate'**][1](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate) module in app dependency.

**EDIT**: See the [updated plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/MWHuea?p=info).

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ngAnimate']);
```

Just remember to download and include the resource.